# Syntax error on token "finally", delete this token AND The method readStream(InputStream) is undefined for the type ParkActivity

Tags: java, android

I am rather new to Android programming and Java in general (like… one week of experience [:))](http://xkcd.com/541/), so I just can't figure this out. I copied some code directly from [Android reference docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);
    finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I get two errors with this code:

1. `The method readStream(InputStream) is undefined for the type SomethingActivity`
2. `Syntax error on token "finally", delete this token`

How do I fix these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Where did you define the method readStream? It is missing in the context.
2. Why did you put `finally` inside `try`?

try like this:

```
try {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);
}
finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: I put `finally` inside `try` because that's what the documentation had :)

Comment: @JJ56: I am dying to read the *documentation*. Where did you get it?

Comment: @JJ56: That is a mistake by the document writer :)

Comment: Ok. Is there some way to submit the mistake to Google? I can't see any.

Comment: It is a bug in documentation, the closing brace before `finally` is ommited. I checked the sources, there is problem with `{@code }` handling in the javadoc.

Comment: Logged on b.android.com as a documentation bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23236

Answer (score 2):

> Syntax error on token "finally", delete this token

The `finally` block should be outside the `try` block.

Regarding problem 1, I'm not a android programmer :) , but I see a lot of similar questions here on SO.I guess you can find out yourself.

<strike>**EDIT :** For your new question, the error says what exactly is the problem. As a quick fix, surround the statements with `try-catch`.</strike>